# my-Directive equals a string

Tags: angularjs

I've started to work with dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect directive.  In the examples he shows the directive is being called out with an equals symbol followed by a undefined double quoted string as shown below.

```
<div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="example13data" selected-model="example13model" extra-settings="example13settings"></div>
```

My question what is the equals and undefined quotes used for in this example?  Is this a way to isolate several of these controls on one page, pass parameters to the directive or does it not serve any purpose and is only a matter of coder style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this syntax to pass parameters to the directive, and it has some interesting uses. You can read more about it [here](https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/6282750).

In this particular directive's case, however, it doesn't seem to be doing anything,the documentation for *angularjs-dropdown-multiselect* does not address it. Given that the attribute parameters could still be accessed if `=""` wasn't present, it can be considered style or unnecessary code, perhaps a leftover from a past implementation.

Comment: The reference you provided above is very useful and answers several questions about passing parameters to directives.  Thanks!